# condititonal concatenation of vector depending upon NA position in other vector

Tags: r, dplyr

i have a two vectors , i desire a third vector that is conditional upon NA position of first vector

```
a= c(1,2,NA,NA,3,NA,NA,5)
b= c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")


desired output= c("a","b c d",NA,NA,"e f g",NA,NA,"h")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use grouping via `zoo::na.locf()` to paste the values together through `tapply()`.  Then we replace them in the original vector.

```
replace(a, !is.na(a), tapply(b, zoo::na.locf(a), paste, collapse = " "))
# [1] "a"     "b c d" NA      NA      "e f g" NA      NA      "h"
```

Comment: Could group on cumsum of !is.na, I guess

Comment: @Frank - I tried.  But a new answer came in with the same idea so I will leave as is.

Answer (score 0):

In base R you could do this...

```
x <- a
x[!is.na(a)] <- tapply(b, cumsum(!is.na(a)), paste, collapse=" ")

x
[1] "a"     "b c d" NA      NA      "e f g" NA      NA      "h"
```